# ffmpeg video compressed but not playing in browser

Tags: android, android-studio, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, video-compression

I have integrated `ffmpeg4android lib`. Video compressing is working fine but video is not playing in browser except safari browser. after uploading to server. I have used following command.

```
ffmpeg -y -i <input file.mp4> -strict experimental -r 30 -ab 48000 -ac 2 -ar 22050 -vcodec mpeg4 -b 2097k <output file.mp4>
```

Please Help me. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you play it on ur android device?

Comment: @GyanendraMani: Yes I can

Comment: did you try with videoview ?

Comment: have you tried playing your compressed video in your local windows ?

Comment: @AbuHurairaLakdawala yes I try with custom video view. In that, it is working fine.

Comment: which video player are you using ?

Comment: [FloppyVideoView](https://github.com/eneim/FloppyVideoView)

Comment: @Saveen Yes I tried with VideoView. Video is playing. But not playing in WebView.

Comment: maybe i think the issue is with video codec unsupported in your player...
I think you may try running your videos with jwplayer

Comment: @AbuHurairaLakdawala We used jwPlayer. Also not play this video in browser except safari.

Comment: @AnkitaShah may be video have format issue. You can use your custom player  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39801499/cant-play-this-video-error

Answer (score 3):

Look at the table "Browser compatibility". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

It seems like you're using and unsupported flavour of mp4, due to the usage of an uncommon codec. I suggest you to use the video format H.264 and MP3 in MP4.

Comment: But not problem with format. Because without compress video played fine. But I tried to compress and upload it.Then it's not playing.

Answer (score 1):

You may convert your video in this format..

```
ffmpeg -i mpeg4_video.mp4 -c:v libx264 libx264_from_mpeg4.mp4
```

This would definitely work in all browsers...

JWPlayer recommended!

Comment: libx264 is working with below 6.0. In my application, Target SDK is 23.