# Can't play this video error

Tags: java, android, video, coffeescript

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button clk;
    VideoView videov;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    clk=(Button) findViewById(R.id.video);
    videov=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    }

    public void videoplay(View v){
   String videopath = "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"+R.raw.movie";
    Uri uri =Uri.parse(videopath);
    videov.setVideoURI(uri);
    videov.requestFocus();
    videov.start();

    }
    }
```

Can't play this video error...!! see the picture  [Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jsiF.png)
What to do ?
After pressing play button it says cant play this video..!!
Need solution of this problem.

Comment: Yes it happened, you should go for 3rd party library

Comment: can you tell me how please

Comment: sure pls wait..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi day before yesterday i had same problem and tried almost everything but didn't get any success. After that i used this library and it work fine. Just follow few steps:

**Step1.** Add it to your gradle

```
compile "fm.jiecao:jiecaovideoplayer:4.7.0"
```

**Step2.** Add it as your video play in xml layout.

```
<fm.jiecao.jcvideoplayer_lib.JCVideoPlayerStandard
    android:id="@+id/videoPlayer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**Step 3.** Check from here how to use this library in your class,

```
public class PlayVideoActivity extends BaseActivity {

@BindView(R.id.videoPlayer)
JCVideoPlayerStandard mVideoPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    restoreFromIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
public int getLayout() {
    return R.layout.activity_play_video;
}

//create intent for this activity with all the necessary params
public static Intent createIntent(Context context, String videoUrl) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, PlayVideoActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(ValueConstants.VIDEO_URL, videoUrl);
    return intent;
}

// get video path from intent and play the video here
private void restoreFromIntent(Intent intent) {
    String videoPath = intent.getExtras().getString(ValueConstants.VIDEO_URL);
    mVideoPlayer.setUp(videoPath
            , JCVideoPlayerStandard.SCREEN_LAYOUT_LIST, "");
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (JCVideoPlayer.backPress()) {
        return;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    JCVideoPlayer.releaseAllVideos();
}
}
```

One more bonus thing from my side. You  can do video cache also by using this [library](https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache). Yesterday i found this also.One time play from internet.After it play without internet also.

**Updated answer:**

Above example i have provided for playing online videos from url but this question have problem related to video path problem.

Just Changed this path:

```
String videopath = "android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"+R.raw.movie";
Uri uri =Uri.parse(videopath);
```

To this,

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.yourvideo);
```

Thanks hope this will help you.

Comment: I dont know how to thank you..!! 
but you are like god to me now
Thanks for helping :)

Comment: No problem, try this way and let me know if you get any issue

Comment: How to add step 1 to gradle ?

Comment: Under dependencies.. just copy and paste

Comment: Yes just some that you needed

Comment: NOTE: This project contains Java compilation errors, which can cause rendering failures for custom views. Fix compilation problems first.

too many errors..!!

Do you have team viewer ? 
i will give you my id pass please see the errors and help me, i m new in android developing. Help me if you have time..!!!

Comment: Yes sure, pls send me I'd and password

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild your project then check

Comment: id -- 708 898 577
password -- 892pza