# Play .mov Video file in Android

Tags: android

How to play .mov file video using URL without converting to another format.
Is this possible that we use any video player that support MOV format in android or can we use any library that support MOV format in android studio?

Comment: Why don't you try with `VLC` media player library?

Comment: use third party library take a look from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39801499/cant-play-this-video-error/39804012#39804012