# FFMPEG resize video not working in browser or IOS

Tags: javascript, html, video, ffmpeg

I have tried to compress video using FFMPEG command and it's compress properly but I couldn't see in browser as like original video.

I have used below all command but didn't success.

> ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/test.mp4 -c:v copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -an /var/www/html/test123.mp4
>
> ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/test.mp4 -s 640x480 -c:v copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -an /var/www/html/test123.mp4
>
> ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/test.mp4 -map 0 -c copy -c:v:1 libx264 -c:a:137 libvorbis /var/www/html/test111.mp4
>
> ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/test.mp4 -s 720x960 -b:v 120k -vcodec mpeg1video -acodec copy /var/www/html/test112.mov
>
> ffmpeg -i INPUT -attach /var/www/html/test.mp4 -metadata:s:2 mimetype=application/x-truetype-font /var/www/html/test2.mp4
>
> ffmpeg -y -i "/var/www/html/test.mp4" -c:v libx264 -preset slow -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a libvo_aacenc -b:a 128k "/var/www/html/test2222.mp4"
>
> ffmpeg -y -i "/var/www/html/test.mp4" -ar 22050 -ab 512 -b 700k -f mp4 -s 514*362 -strict -2 -c:a aac "/var/www/html/test2222222.mp4"
>
> ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/test.mp4 -c copy -movflags +faststart /var/www/html/test222.mp4
>
> ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/test.mp4 -c copy -movflags +faststart /var/www/html/test222.mp4
>
> ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/test.mp4 -s 720x480 -c:a copy /var/www/html/test22.mp4

[ffmpeg video compressed but not playing in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39658508/ffmpeg-video-compressed-but-not-playing-in-browser)

> ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/test.mp4 -c:v libx264 /var/www/html/test111.mp4
>
> ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/test.mp4 -r 60 -s hd720 /var/www/html/test111.mp4

Do you have any Idea? How to compress video as like Original with work in All browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like:

```
./ffmpeg -y -i /var/www/html/test.mp4 -s 1280x720 -c:v libx264 -b 3M -strict -2 -movflags faststart /var/www/html/testOBM.mp4
```

The above will give you a 1280x720 output, at 3Mbps using h264 in an mp4 container, and will then do a second pass to move the moov element to the front of the file enabling it to start streaming faster (see this answer for some more detail).

You may want to adjust the framesize and bitrate depending on quality and connection speed you want to support